# Bootstrap Drop Down - Not Dropping Down When id in URL

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

Running into an interesting issue with a site I am building.  The dropdown menu for one option stops working when I get to a url that includes an id in it.

As an example, if I am at http://localhost/degs/serpstudentsinclass.php?id=3, if I click on the Admin dropdown nothing happens.  If I click back to the home page http://localhost/degs/index.php, Admin drop down menu starts working no problem.

This also adds an additional issue when working from a mobile device.  Once you reach http://localhost/degs/serpstudentsinclass.php?id=3, you completely lose the ability to use the navigation menu (as now it's a complete drop down menu due to screen size).  So you have to again go back to the index.php and then the menu will begin to work again.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Header file

```
<?php
// session file
include_once 'includes/session.php';?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">




    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">DEGS</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="serpentine.php">Serpentine</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="uturn_box.php">U-Turn Box</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="blocked_evasive.php">Blocked Evasive</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="forward_reverse.php">Forward Reverse</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="controlled_braking.php">Controlled Braking</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="cumulative_skills_day.php">Cumulative Skills - Day</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="cumulative_skills_night.php">Cumulative Skills - Night</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="evoc_challenge.php">Evoc Challenge</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Admin
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="users.php">Users</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="classes.php">Classes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="students.php">Students</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="legends.php">Legend</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="tests.php">Tests</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <?php
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
                        ?>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Page where problems start - other pages follow a similar pattern where you select the class to get the list of students.

```
<?php
$title = "DEGS - Students";
require_once 'includes/header.php';
require_once 'includes/auth_check.php';
require_once 'db/conn.php';

if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo 'error';
} else {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $results = $admin->getStudents($id);
    $class = $admin->getClassDetails($id);
    $students = $admin->getStudents($id);


}
?>
<h1>Serpentine - Class <?php echo $class['class']?></h1>

<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Agency</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th># of Attempts</th>
        <th>Student Operations</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($r = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r['lname']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r['fname']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r['agency']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $class[1]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $serpentine->getAttemptCount($r['student_id']) ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="serpview.php?id=<?php echo $r['student_id']?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Attempts</a>
                <a href="serpadd.php?id=<?php echo $r['student_id']?>" class="btn btn-success">Add Attempt</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  I didn't include my footer at the end!  Hope this helps anyone else who run into this issue!